# The distribution of xtΣx

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

For the multivariate gaussian distribution $x$, what is the distribution of $x^T\Sigma^{-1}x$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$, then $X=\mu + \Sigma^{1/2} Z$ where $Z \sim N(0,I)$.

If $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$, then
$$X^\top \Sigma^{-1} X = Z^\top \Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma^{1/2} Z = Z^\top Z\sim \chi^2_n.$$

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I have the question. What If $X$ has different covariance matrix? still, does it follow chi square distribution?

Comment: @kw1924 What do you mean? The above covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is arbitrary.

Comment: What i mean is that $X \sim N(0,\Sigma')$.

Comment: @kw1924 The above argument shows it is $\chi^2_n$...